# Rationality of artan(2/pi)

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers, pi, wolfram-alpha

I was messing around on Wolfram Alpha and I saw that the conversion of arctan(2/pi) from radians to degrees was 32.48. Wolfram Alpha usually shows more decimal spaces, so I was wondering where this is rational or not.

Comment: Probably easier to try with your pocket calculator to see if there are more digits.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem

Comment: @lhf: Unless I'm turned-around, Niven's theorem doesn't apply. Niven's theorem (and extensions to constructible numbers -- see pp. 255-257 of Amer. Math. Monthly 29 (1922) [internet archive](https://archive.org/details/americanmathema04amergoog/page/n261/mode/2up) & [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=sr4EAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA255)) concerns when the values of trig functions evaluated at rational degree inputs are rational/constructible, and nothing about their values for irrational degree inputs. Here the degree input $\arctan \frac{2}{\pi}$ is not a priori known to be rational.

Comment: Correction: "extensions to constructible numbers" should be "extensions to quadratic irrationals", at least regarding the reference I gave.

Comment: The number is $$32.48163659052975359744\cdots$$

Comment: I don't know why the value was rounded to $32.48$ in [this computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arctan%282%2Fpi%29), but [this other computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28180%2Fpi%29*arctan%282%2Fpi%29) gives many more decimal digits (especially when you click "More digits" several times).